# Вывод значения -1U

Tags: c++, вывод, language-lawyer, стандарт, неопределённое-поведение

Кто может объяснить почему выводит 4294967295?

```
#include <iostream>

signed main() {
  std::cout << -1u << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Неопределённого поведения тут нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115451/discussion-on-question-by-------1u).

Comment: Похоже, это один из исторических вопросов ruStackOverflow. История правок - огонь

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Целочисленный литерал `1u` имеет тип `unsigned int`.
2. Операнд унарного минуса подвергается целочисленному продвижению (integral promotion). В данном случае тип значения, к которому будет применён унарный минус останется без изменения — `unsigned int`.
3. Для беззнакового значения `x` результат применения унарного минуса равен `2**n - x`, где `n` — количество бит в продвинутом операнде. Если тип `unsigned int` — 32-битный, то получим следующий результат:

   ```
   2**32 - 1 == 4294967296 - 1 == 4294967295
   ```

[expr.unary.op/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#8):

> The operand of the unary `-` operator shall have arithmetic or unscoped enumeration type and the result is the negative of its operand. **Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration operands. The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from `2**n`, where `n` is the number of bits in the promoted operand.** The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.